# How can I do for loop with long value

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, int, long-integer

I need to do codes with for loop and long value like this:

```
for(long i=1;i<lines.length; i++){

    char tmp = lines[i].charAt(lines[i].length()-1);

    int index = lines[i].lastIndexOf(" ");

    lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, index);

    if(tmp != lastChar)
        lines[i] = "S" + lines[i];
    else
        lines[i]=" "+lines[i];

    lastChar = tmp;        
}
```

The problem is: `incompatible  types:possible lossy conversion from long to int` I don't know how to fix it

Comment: It would help if you mentioned which programming language this is

Comment: I'm guessing, Java

Comment: Yes Java sry didn't mention that

Answer (score 2):

you are using long in for loop that is correct but when you are using index in `lines[i]` then problem start. java says index is always int but in your case it is long.

and long can not cast directly into int.either change long data type to int data type in for loop or  cast `i` variable when you are using as index like `lines[(int)i]`(not prefer).